# WSO2 Mediator for external OAuth2 identity provider integration

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to enrich an API call using a Mediator to invoke an external identity provider's token endpoint and get the access token to be passed to the backend service inside the **Authorization** header.

According to the `curl` I used to get an access token in the command line, I have to create an HTTP POST request towards the identity provider's token endpoint with **content-type header** set to "`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`" and **body** set to "`grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={SECRET}&audience={CLIENT_ID}`". I tried also https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/Use+OAuth2+Protected+Backends but if I correctly understood, it is used an XML notation to invoke the service and I fear it is not supported by the identity provider's token endpoint